# What is a difference between ROS Multimaster and ROS Master-Slave

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to understand the difference between [ROS Multimaster](http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster) and [ROS Master-Slave-API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Master_Slave_APIs) but it is confusing me.
Please help to understand the difference between them.
There is a lot of tutorials available on the web but none of them explains what is Multimaster and Master-Salve-API, there is no in-depth explanation about them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331884/what-is-a-difference-between-ros-multimaster-and-ros-master-slave/) by [MuhammadDanyial](https://answers.ros.org/users/43673/muhammaddanyial/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-08-28**:
Please edit your question to provide more details about what you're specifically referring to. There are several terms similar to what you refer to but your question does not have enough information to tell exactly what you want to compare.  Links would be helpful.

**Comment by [MuhammadDanyial](https://answers.ros.org/users/43673/muhammaddanyial/) on 2019-08-29**:
I have added more explanation to my question, is it enough now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The multimaster package that you link to is a ROS package that was last released many years ago and hasn't been supported for several distros.

If you're looking for multi master capabilities I'd recommend checking out [multimaster_fkie](http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie) or [rocon_multimaster](http://wiki.ros.org/rocon_multimaster)

The Master-Slave API you link to is the internal APIs that ROS uses under the hood to coordinate between nodes. There are not tutorials for it as it's not considered a user facing API and you're generally not recommended to interact with it directly.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1